# Points between two rays from the origin: open?

Tags: general-topology

Consider two [rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Ray) with their outset in $(0,0)$, and let $A$ denote the shaded region between (but not including) these two rays. More specificly, in order to shade $A$, we start at the $x$-axis and rotate in positive direction until we meet the first ray. The region on the "other side" of this ray is shaded all the way until we meet the second ray.... but, again, the rays themselves are not part of $A$. The question is, is $A$ open?

Visually, it's obvious, since its kind of like a triangle with legs of infinite size, and the legs are not included in the set. But how does one show it mathematically?

My attempt is to notice that we can define $A$ as the set $\{x \ | \ m(x) \in (\theta, \phi) \}$ where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are radian angles, and $m$ is a function which returns the positive angle $x$ makes with the $x$-axis. If $m$ was continuous, we can appeal to how preimages of continuous functions act on open sets ... but $m$ is not a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is it?

So what then?

Answer (score 1):

You can write $A$ as an intersection of "half-planes", i.e. sets of the type

$$A_k = \{(x,y)| y > kx\}$$

for appropriatelly chosen values of $k$. It is fairly simple to prove that $A_k$ is an open set for every $k\in\mathbb R$, since it is a preimage of an open set $(0,\infty)$ given a continuous function $f(x,y) = kx-y$.

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly what you had in mind, but assume line $1$ is the $x$-axis and line $2$ is the $y$-axis, just as an example. The set $A$ is then the first quadrant, excluding the two axis. Is the idea then to first write $$\{ y  \le 0\}$$, which is closed, and $\bigcap_{k \ge 1} \{ y \ge kx\}$, which is closed as well, and then the intersection of these, which are the other 3 quadrants, is closed, and so the complement is open?  If this is correct, how do I generalize it for all $A$? The rays are given through radian angles, and not slopes.